# Custom Javascript doesn't work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, safari, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce site and I have purchased 2 plugins to give the ability to customize the item in my product page.
The plugin demo can be found [here](http://fancyproductdesigner.com/product/sneaker-mspc/):

In this demo there are 2 plugins, one called Multistep Product Configurator (MSPC) which is the tabs at the top of the page and a second one called Fancy Product Designer (FPD) which is the product display panel underneath it.

I wanted to use these two plugins to display them one next to each other in order to avoid scrolling down the page to see the changes made with MSPC plugin.

So I have been trying to customise the css code for hours with no success.
You can see my page [here](http://www.elefante-boa.com/product/elefante-boa/): 
I ended up using a custom javascript code in my theme's custom js section which basically repositions the wrapper a few seconds after the page loads.

My issue is that with the js code I achieved what I wanted in all browsers except safari!

Here is the code I used:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(document.readyState === 'complete'){
     setTimeout(function () {
         var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mspc-wrapper");
         x[0].style.float = "none";
     }, 3000);
 }
```

}

Any idea why it doesn't work in Safari browser?
Feel free to try fixing this with CSS but I am pretty sure it doesn't work...
Any feedback much appreciated.

Comment: `x[0].style.float = "none";` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I believe that the word 'float' is reserved in Javascript, and that is why we have to use those other syntaxes. The above code seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE 11, though I have not tried it in Safari.

Comment: `HTMLElement.style` is nothing but an object..and `float` can be and is property of that object..

Comment: Nope, its not reserved when referring it as a property. I actually have no idea how this worked in chrome etc. It shouldn't possible work from what I know. If it does I'd love to know how, genuinely.

Comment: @JamieHutber after a quick search I have found this --> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp
So, it seems logical that it works, why wouldn't it ?

Comment: Because that is the correct syntax with `cssFloat` the OP has used `styleFloat`. I also didn't see the second line where he uses `cssFloat` :). Still, why use that when `style.float` is supported across all browsers

Comment: @JamieHutber You are right. I have removed the style.float and left only the cssFloat but still not working...

Comment: I have updated my code in original post as I have it right now. It still works on all browsers except safari.

Comment: @RayonDabre @JamieHutber, I stand corrected, using just `style.float` was the correct way to go. Still, as he says not working in Safari, quite strange!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code for changing the styles is wrong:

```
 x[0].style.styleFloat //returns undefined
```

You'll be wanting to use

```
x[0].style.float = 'none';
```

If this doesn't work make sure the js is even running :)

Comment: Problem has to be with cssFloat || styleFloat
I changed with what you suggested but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't seem to support the state 'complete'. Try using 'loaded' instead (if it doesn't matter whether the document has been *fully* loaded or just loaded) since it seems to be supported by all browsers.
[Reference](http://caniuse.com/#search=complete)

Just to make sure, try debugging it or throwing in a console.log to see if the if-statement ever returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

Thanks a lot for taking a time to respond to this. What I had to do was to add a hook inside the content-single-product.php and then I could fix it with the CSS code.

I didn't need to add the javascript in the end.

Thanks for replying though!